# Detect when tooltip is outside of overlay wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, overflow, viewport

I am trying to figure out how to detect when this tooltip is overflowing the main div so I can change its class. When the container has overflow hidden on it it is outside of the view for the user, so i need to change every last element of the row (or any that leave the wrapper) so the tooltip is on the other side.

See screenshot:

[image]

I have tried every persons code that I can find on here but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your specific code I can only make basic recommendations, but here's how I've detected it before using jQuery (my example detects overflow of the viewport on the x-axis, but could easily be modified for your parent div).

```
jQuery('#mainnav .menu > .menu-item').hover(function(){
    var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var submenuLeft = jQuery(this).offset().left;
    var submenuRight = submenuLeft+jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').width();
    if (submenuRight > viewportWidth) {
        jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').css('left', 'auto').css('right', '0');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').css('left', '0').css('right', 'auto');
    }       
}, function(){
        jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').css('left', '-9999px').css('right', 'auto');
});
```

Basically, on hover this sets variables for the width of the viewport (you can change this to your parent div), the left position of the submenu (this would be your tooltip), the right position of the submenu (again, your tooltip) by adding its width to its left position. Then, if the right position has a larger x value than the viewport width, set the css to one thing, else set it to the default.

Since writing that snippet, I'd now recommend using .addClass() instead of .css(), but this illustrates the idea a little easier.
Hope that helps, or at least gives you some food for thought.

Comment: Hey thanks, this seems to be matching all of the elements rather than just the end items that actually do overlap. It is always matching on the last function as well.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you mean, you'll need to change the selector at the beginning too. You might be able to get away with a more specific selector than mine as well.

As for the last function, that will always trigger because it is the hover out function (to hide the submenu/tooltip).

Comment: Yeah I did change the viewportWidth but still nothing, not quite sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Can you put what you have into a jsFiddle? It'd be easier to troubleshoot that way.